# Two queries run much longer when combined into one

Tags: sqlite

The first two queries below are very similar. The third is practically the union of the first two:

```
sql> SELECT sigla_partido, SUM(receita_valor) 
     FROM prestacao_conta_eleicao_candidato_2014
     NATURAL JOIN prestacao_conta_eleicao_candidato_2014_receita
     GROUP BY sigla_partido

[2016-03-07 22:54:55] 32 row(s) retrieved starting from 1 in 352ms (439ms total)

sql> SELECT sigla_partido, SUM(despesa_valor) 
     FROM prestacao_conta_eleicao_candidato_2014
     NATURAL JOIN prestacao_conta_eleicao_candidato_2014_despesas
     GROUP BY sigla_partido

[2016-03-07 22:54:59] 32 row(s) retrieved starting from 1 in 1s 648ms (1s 832ms total)

sql> SELECT sigla_partido, SUM(receita_valor), SUM(despesa_valor) 
     FROM prestacao_conta_eleicao_candidato_2014
     NATURAL JOIN prestacao_conta_eleicao_candidato_2014_receita
     NATURAL JOIN prestacao_conta_eleicao_candidato_2014_despesas
     GROUP BY sigla_partido

[2016-03-07 22:55:30] 32 row(s) retrieved starting from 1 in 18s 264ms (29s 932ms total)
```

I expected the runtime of the third query to be close to the sum of the execution times of the first two queries. That did not happen and the third query took much longer than expected. For what reason?

Comment: It would be good if we could have a) the table structures of the three tables, b) how many records in each and c) the cardinality of the indexes. I do agree that it is puzzling. What's even more puzzling - you actually have **32**  parties in Brazil? And I thought Irish politics were complicated. :-)

Comment: An union would be written with [UNION (ALL)](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound), and that might be what you actually want …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better combine those queries using Derived Tables;

```
select sigla_partido, receita_valor, despesa_valor
from
 (
     SELECT sigla_partido, SUM(receita_valor) as receita_valor
     FROM prestacao_conta_eleicao_candidato_2014
     NATURAL JOIN prestacao_conta_eleicao_candidato_2014_receita
     GROUP BY sigla_partido
  ) as receita
natural join 
 (
     SELECT sigla_partido, SUM(despesa_valor) as despesa_valor
     FROM prestacao_conta_eleicao_candidato_2014
     NATURAL JOIN prestacao_conta_eleicao_candidato_2014_despesas
     GROUP BY sigla_partido
 ) as despesas
```

Btw, check if the slow query actually returned the correct result.

Comment: It is work faster! But, you could say why my sql is very slow?

Comment: @Macabeus: I don't know about your PKs/FKs, but there's a high probablity that joining both SELECTs results in an m:n-join, i.e. there are multiple rows for the same value on both sides. As you join all rows from the left table to all matching rows from the right table you will increase the number of rows, it's always multiplying those numbers, e.g. 10 rows in A with the same value and 5 in B result in 10*5=50 rows, only a PK-FK-join (1:n) is correct. That's why I wrote *check if the slow query actually returned the correct result*, if you got that problem it will return a much higher value.